# Checking if a $1$-form $\omega$ is closed

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I must verify if the $1$-form $\omega = x^2 y dx -3xy^2 dy$ is closed. My computation is as follows:
\begin{align}
d\omega &= d(x^2 y)\wedge dx + d(-3xy^2)\wedge dy\\
&= (2xy\; dx + x^2 dy)\wedge dx + (-3y^2 \; dx - 6xy\; dy)\wedge dy\\
&= x^2\; dy\wedge dx - 3y^2\; dx\wedge dy\\
&= (-x^2-3y^2)dx\wedge dy \neq 0
\end{align}
Hence, $\omega$ is not closed. I don't think I made any mistakes; is this calculation ok?

Comment: Yes, it’s fine.